# Compare for min values in nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I have a list of pairwise dictionary that goes like this:

```
[{'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Ben': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'melon': 1}},
 {'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Cam': {'star': 65, 'melon': 1}},
 {'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Den': {'juice': 0, 'cake': 4}}, ...]
```

I need to compare the pairs for min value(in fraction) but we only focus on the items in focal person, in this case Anna.

Take the first pair for example,

the items that 'Anna' and 'Ben' have in common are 'star' and 'banana'. Since we only care about the focal person 'Anna', we just need to find the min of 'star', 'banana', and 'bag'.

Then, subtract with 1 after comparing the pair for min values:

```
Ans = 1 - min('star':[5/24, 5/18], 'banana':[12/24, 12/24], 'bag':[7/24, 0])
```

So the ideal result will be

```
Anna-Ben = Ans1
Anna-Cam = Ans2
Anna-Den = Ans3
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thank you so much and sorry for my english!

*Edit:

Hi, thanks for your reply, but the thing I want is 1 minus the min of each item. Like in the 'Anna-Ben' pair,

min of 'star' between [5/24, 5/18] is 5/24,

min of 'banana' between [12/24, 12/18] is 12/24, and

min of 'bag' between [7/24, 0] is 0 (only Anna has bag, Ben doesn't has bag so it's zero).

And we ignore the 'melon' item in 'Ben' because we only concern the focal person 'Anna'.

So the final result should be [1 - 5/24 - 12/24 - 0 = 7/24] for the 'Anna-Ben' pair.

Comment: Do you want one min for all items? I mean the min between the min of each item?

Comment: It's really helpful when writing questions with code to use code that's valid. It's hard to understand what you mean by `Ans = 1 - min('star':[5/24, 5/18], 'banana':[12/24, 12/24], 'bag':[7/24, 0])` because it is not valid python. What is `Ans` supposed to be here? A dictionary? A single value? A list?

Comment: @palvarez I want the min of each item, like the min of 'star' between the pair.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yea you're right, I'm sorry. Ans is supposed to be a floating point value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

```
data = [
  {'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Ben': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'melon': 1}},
  {'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Cam': {'star': 65, 'melon': 1}},
  {'Anna': {'star': 5, 'banana': 12, 'bag': 7}, 'Den': {'juice': 0, 'cake': 4}}
]

results = {}
# iterate over each pair
for pair in data:
  anna_data = pair.pop("Anna")
  other_name, other_data = pair.popitem()  # get comparing data

  result = 1
  anna_sum = float(sum(anna_data.values()))
  other_sum = float(sum(other_data.values()))

  # iterate over each of anna's item
  for item, anna_val in anna_data.items():
    other_val = other_data.get(item, 0)  # set 0 if the item is not found in other_data
    min_item = min(anna_val/anna_sum, other_val/other_sum)
    result -= min_item
  # save the result to a wonderful dict
  key = "Anna-%s" % other_name
  results[key] = result
print(results)
```

Result:

```
{'Anna-Ben': 0.29166666666666663, 'Anna-Cam': 0.7916666666666666,'Anna-Den': 1.0}
```

By the way I destroyed the data list, if you want to keep it intact make a copy() of it before computing this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but the thing I want is 1 minus the min of each item. Like in the 'Anna-Ben' pair, the min of 'star' between [5/24, 5/18] is 5/24, min of 'banana' between [12/24, 12/18] is 12/24, and the min of 'bag' between [7/24, 0] is 0 (only Anna has bag, Ben doesn't has bag so it's zero). And we ignore the 'melon' item in 'Ben' because we only concern the focal person 'Anna'. So the final result should be [1 - 5/24 - 12/24 - 0 = 7/24] for the 'Anna-Ben' pair.

Comment: @Alex There you go!

Comment: Wow thanks! What if I have focal person named other than 'Anna'? Cause my pairs go like A-B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D, and so on.

Comment: @Alex What is your criteria when choosing the focal person? remember dictionaries do not have order.

Comment: I don't really have a criteria, I just have a list of name and I use itertools.combinations function to generate pairs, and the focal person is the one in the first place. For instance, if A-B, then A is the focal person, if B-C, then B become the focal person.

Comment: @Alex Maybe you have something like this? https://pastebin.com/xUjp0Dmw No need to create dict of pairs, you lose the information of the focal person.